# Question about the union of an empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I would like some clarification regarding the following text from a textbook:

> There is no problem with these definitions if one of the elements of $\mathscr{A}$ happens to be the empty set. But it is a bit tricky to decide what (if anything) these definitions mean if we allow $\mathscr{A}$ to be the empty collection. Applying the definitions literally, we see that no element of $x$ satisfies the defining property for the union of the elements of $\mathscr{A}$. So it is reasonable to say that $$ \bigcup_{A \in \mathscr{A}}A=\emptyset$$
>
> If $\mathscr{A}$ is empty. On the other hand, every $x$ satisfies (vacuously) the defining property for the intersection of the elements of $\mathscr{A}$.

I wanted to know why we don't say that every $x$ vacuously satisfies the defining property for the union of the elements of $\mathscr{A}$? Does it just come down to convention?

Comment: We use "vacuously" for a condition which is either (i) an implication in which the premise is always false; or (ii) a universally quantified condition in which the elements are taken from the empty set. (One can view it as an instance of the same thing, since "for all $x\in\varnothing$ `blah`" is equivalent to "for all $x$ (if $x\in \varnothing$ then `blah`". This is the case for the intersection. For the union, however, what you have is an existential condition that can never be satisfied, or a conjunction where one clause is always false. So it is not "vacuously satisfied".

Comment: How would the conjunction look for the existential condition, as an example?

Comment: In this case it is $\exists A(A\in\varnothing \wedge x\in A)$. The clause $A\in\varnothing$ is always false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where's the witness?  It can be helpful to think of these definitions asserting the existence (or absence) of a particular object which satisfies (i.e., is a witness for) some property.

For the union of the empty collection, for $x$ to be in the union, there must be an $A \in \mathscr{A}$ with $x \in A$.  That is, $A$ is a witness of the membership of $x$ in the union.  Since there is no candidate $A$ in $\mathscr{A}$, there is no witness to the inclusion of $x$ in the union.  Consequently, $x$ is not in the union.

For the intersection of the empty collection, an element $x$ is in the intersection if $x$ is in every member of $\mathscr{A}$.  This means that a single $A \in \mathscr{A}$ such that $x \not\in A$ is a witness to $x$ not in the intersection.  However, there is no candidate $A$ in $\mathscr{A}$ to act as a witness of the *absence* of $x$ in the intersection.  Consequently, $x$ must be in the intersection.

Comment: I was wondering how we could apply similar reasoning for the intersection when $\mathscr{A}$ is nonempty? So let's say the two sets $A_{1}=\{1,2\}$ and $A_{2}=\{2,3,4\}$ are in $\mathscr{A}$. Then do we automatically say that the intersection of the sets $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$ is $2$, without thinking in terms of a witness? Or does it work more like a "ruling out" process? For example, the element $3$ is not in $A_{1}$ and thus $A_{1}$ is a witness to $3$ not in the intersection of $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$. And so a similar process is done with the elements $1,2,$ and $4$?

Comment: @K.M : That can be a useful way to think about it.  I tend to think "$A_1$ is a witness to exclude anything other than $1$ and $2$ and $A_2$ also witnesses the exclusion of $1$."

Answer (score 1):

$x\in\bigcup\mathscr{A}$ means you have to actually exhibit an $A\in\mathscr{A}$ such that $x\in A$.

On the other hand, $x\in\bigcap\mathscr{A}$ means $x\in A$ for every $A\in\mathscr{A}$, so this is vacuous.